# How system listen to file change?

Tags: linux, node.js, operating-system, filesystems

In **OS** level,how can it achieve knowing something's changed(like file changing)

e.g:
In node,we can monitor a file and perform some actions while it changes

```
fs.watch(file_path,function(){
  //do something while the file's changed;
});
```

can someone give me a brief intuition/idea/keyword about how it really works

one I can come up is that while I hit `:w` in vim ,it somehow invoke some system *fake_save_file* function,and inside this *fake_save_file* function,it dispatch some events to somewhere else

Comment: Linux has [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) which can be used to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

You might know that the kernel indexes the files in file system as file descriptors. File watching is achieved by listening to changes to those file descriptors. In linux [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) does that.

Whenever you open, read, write/modify or move a file, the kernel issues operations upon the file descriptor. Inotify extends the filesystem by tracking these operations and showing them to you.

The example you gave is somewhat incorrect. The fake_save_file is created by your text editor vim to store the temporary changes made unless you the user actually saves it. When you save it with `:w` the editor replaces your actual_save_file with a copy of fake_save_file.

As a user you would be watching your actual_save_file. This gets changed when you enter `:w` in vim. You will be notified as vim modified its contents.

Answer (score 0):

[pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) is might be you want.please check it.